# Create StratifiedK-Folds from a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

Let's say that I have a PandasDataFrame `df` like so:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|         ID          |     Value        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          12         |        32        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          354        |        43        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

> Values are random.

I want to split this data into different folds using `sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold`. What I want is to add another column `df[kfold]` which will  correspond to the particular fold number that was optained by splitting the `dataframe`. Is it possible ?

Comment: You can do that. In this case, after you obtain the split from StratifiedKFold, save the information about which row went as training and which for testing before creating a model. Then, update your dataframe accordingly with this new information. I hope this answers your query,

Comment: If you don't mind would you be able to show an example. I am kinda new to `pandas`  and `sklearn` . Thanks .